# Magento 2 System config Categories list not working on website scope update

Tags: magento2, system-configuration, source-model, caltegories-list

> I have created a system configuration to show the Categories list as assigned website-wise.
> When we change the website scope the categories list options are the same.

Would you please share your thoughts on the same?

> system.xml

```
<field id="categorylist" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
  <label>Categories List </label>
  <source_model>Prince\MyModule\Model\Source\Categories</source_model>
</field>
```

> Model/Source/Categories.php

```
<?php
namespace Prince\MyModule\Model\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category;

class Categories implements ArrayInterface
{
    public const ALL_CATEGORIES = 0;
    public const SYSTEM_CATEGORY_ID = 1;
    public const ROOT_LEVEL = 1;


    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $requestInterface;
    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    private $categoryHelper;

    /**
     * Categories constructor.
     *
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $requestInterface
     * @param Category $categoryHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        RequestInterface $requestInterface,
        Category $categoryHelper
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->requestInterface = $requestInterface;
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    }


    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $optionArray = [];
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        foreach ($arr as $value => $label) {
            $optionArray[] = [
                'value' => $value,
                'label' => $label
            ];
        }
        return $optionArray;
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        
        $catIdAsWebsite = $this->storeManager->getGroup()->getRootCategoryId();

        return $this->getChildren(self::SYSTEM_CATEGORY_ID, self::ROOT_LEVEL,$catIdAsWebsite);
    }

    
    private function getChildren($parentCategoryId, $level,catIdAsWebsite)
    {
      
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentCategoryId);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('level', $level);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
        
            $options[$category->getId()] = $category->getLevel();
            if ($category->hasChildren()) {
                $options = array_replace($options, $this->getChildren($category->getId(), $category->getLevel() + 1,$catIdAsStoreId));
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please replace your current code with the following code.**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package VendorName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class Categories implements ArrayInterface
{
    const PREFIX_ROOT = '';
    const REPEATER = '- ';
    const PREFIX_END = '';

    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $_categoryResourceFactory;

    protected $_category;

    protected $_request;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_options = array();

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryResourceFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Category $category,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_categoryResourceFactory = $categoryResourceFactory;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_category = $category;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }

    public function setInputId($value)
    {
        return $this->setId($value);
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $store = $this->_request->getParam('store', 1);
            if (!$store) {
                $rootCategoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore("1")->getRootCategoryId();
                $label = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($rootCategoryId);
                $categories = array(array('value' => $rootCategoryId, 'label' => $label));
            } else {
                $rootCategoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId();
                $label = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($rootCategoryId);
                $categories = array(array('value' => $rootCategoryId, 'label' => $label));

            }
            $options = [];
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $this->_options = array();
                if ($category['value']) {
                    $_categories = $this->_categoryResourceFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $category['value']);
                    if ($_categories) {
                        $rootOption = array('label' => $category['label']);
                        foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
                            $this->_options[] = array(
                                'label' => self::PREFIX_ROOT . $_category->getName(),
                                'value' => $_category->getEntityId(),
                            );
                            if ($_category->hasChildren()) {
                                $this->_getChildOptions($_category->getChildren());
                            }
                        }

                        if ($this->_options) {
                            $options[] = array(
                                'label' => $category['label'],
                                'value' => $this->_options,
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->_options[] = $options;
        }
        $treeData = [];
        $skip = 0;
        foreach ($this->_options as $treekey => $treevalue) {
            if ($skip) {
                if (isset($treevalue['label'])) {
                    $treeData[$treevalue['value']] = $treevalue['label'];
                }
            }
            $skip++;
        }
        return $treeData;
    }

    protected function _getChildOptions($categories)
    {
        $categories = explode(",", $categories);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category);
            $prefix = str_repeat(self::REPEATER, $category->getLevel() * 1) . self::PREFIX_END;
            $this->_options[] = array(
                'label' => $prefix . $category->getName(),
                'value' => $category->getEntityId(),
            );
            if ($category->hasChildren()) {
                $this->_getChildOptions($category->getChildren());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very thankful to you for your reply. I just wanted to know if it's working on the website scope. I see you are taking the store from the request parameters.
I have used this type of solution for "store" but when we filter the data as website level then not get the correct value:
As we know the root category is assigned as website level.
Thanks

Comment: @PrinceKumar You can retrieve the website ID based on your current store and then obtain the root category ID. After that, please update the above code to assign the root category ID.